# Segmentation fault showing after no. of columns reaches to 3

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, out-of-memory

Whenever I select the length of columns more than 3,it shows segmentation fault. It executes the code and shows no. of rows correctly but restricts the no. of columns to 3 only.
'''

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j,r,c;
    int arr1[r][c];
    printf("Enter no. of rows in the array: ");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    printf("Enter no. of columns in the array: ");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    printf("Enter elements in %dX%d array:\n",r,c);
    for ( i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&arr1[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Your entered array is:\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",arr1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Transpose of the array is:\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < r; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",arr1[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

'''

Comment: Enable warnings in your compiler and elevate warnings to errors.  With Clang, start with `-Wmost -Werror`. With GCC, start with `-Wall -Werror`. With MSVC, start with `/W3 /WX`. You should not expect `int arr1[r][c];` to work because `r` and `c` have not been set to any values before that statement. C does not dynamically adjust array sizes according to variables. An array is created once at a specific size and keeps that size throughout its lifetime. The behavior of your program is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: In MSVC, you may want `/permissive-` too - and `-pedantic` in gcc and clang.

Comment: I'm blown away that a modern compiler doesn't issue a warning on something like this.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - MSVC doesn't support variable sized arrays, even for C code. The above code wouldn't compile on MSVC even if `r` and `c` had been assigned values.

Comment: @selbie Ahh, yes, correct. I jumped on the MSVC wagon when Eric mentioned MSVC above :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first two lines of code in `main()` are undefined behavior.

```
int i,j,r,c;
int arr1[r][c];
```

Neither `r` nor `c` are initialized, but you use them to create a 2d array `arr1`. `r` and `c` will contain some garbage values which could be any integer. If they are negative or `0`, creating `arr1` would fail. If they are positive but very large, creating `arr1` could fail too.

After declaring your variables, you use `scanf()` to initialize them, but the array is already created, so you need to switch the order. First create `r` and `c`, then get the user input from `scanf()` and initialize them with it and then create the 2d array `arr1`.